# angular2-grid directory is not insalled

Tags: node.js, angular

I am relatively new to angular 2. I want to use angular2-grid directory. What I have done is creating a folder for my application with all necessary starting file and then run **npm-install**. Installation is completed and the demo application is working after I typed **npm start**. Then I want to set up angular2-grid and in the [official website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-grid)  is saying to use it you simply have to run **npm install angular2-grid**. I tried that but I got some warning like :

> npm WARN angular2-grid@2.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.4
>   but none was installed. npm WARN angular2-grid@2.0.1 requires a peer
>   of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed. npm WARN angular2-grid@2.0.1
>   requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.

I need some help how to overcome this problem. Any suggestion is welcome.

My `package.json` below:

```
{
"name": "product-management",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "Deborah Kurata",
"description": "Package for the Acme Product Management sample application",
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
},
"license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",

    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
},
"repository": {}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share your package.json?

Comment: @suraj I posted it below

Comment: your existing angular version and rxjs version is lower than what `angular-grid` requires. Either go for an older version of `angular-grid` or update your project if possible

Comment: run  'npm update @angular/core' to update angular/core to the latest version or 'npm install @angular/core@2.4.4' if you need actually this version (also for rxjs and zong.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your existing `Angular version` and `RXJS version` is lower than what angular-grid requires. Either go for an older version of angular-grid or update your project if possible

For your angular2-grid to be added as a dependency in package.json you need to do

```
npm install angular2-grid --save
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
"name": "product-management",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "Deborah Kurata",
"description": "Package for the Acme Product Management sample application",
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
},
"license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",

    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
},
"repository": {}
}
```

Comment: @suraj Something which seems strange to me is that angular2-grid exists as a library in **node_modules** directory. Does it man I have already installed it?

Comment: yes.. for it to be added as a dependency in package.json you need to do `npm install angular2-grid --save`

Comment: @suarj. Thanks mate. Now everything is going well. Post your answer not as a comment so I can give you a tick